# Entity Framework double foreign key column from fluent mapping

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a legacy SQL Server database with legacy entity structures (I can NOT change the database or the entities in this case)

Tables:

**Companies**:

```
   Id (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
   Name (varchar(200), not null)
```

**Locations**:

```
   Id (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
   CompanyId (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
   Name (varchar(200), not null)
```

Entities:

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Model with mapping:

```
public partial class CompanyModel : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("CompanyId"));
    }
}
```

Sample program:

```
var guid = Guid.Parse("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX");

using (var mod = new CompanyModel())
{
   var company = mod.Companies.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == guid);
   var locations = company.Locations;
}
```

If I now run this program the SQL trace produces the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
[Extent1].[Company_Id1] AS [Company_Id1]
FROM [dbo].[Locations] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Company_Id1] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Company_Id1] = @EntityKeyValue1)',N'@EntityKeyValue1 uniqueidentifier',@EntityKeyValue1='XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

As you can see the Company_Id1 is included. If I did not map the column in the OnModelCreating, I would have gotten Company_Id and Compan_Id1

I'm sure the issue lies with my mapping, any assistance there would be appreciated.

Comment: have you done any migrations yet?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to include the FK property in the Entity model.  This also gives you convention-based configuration for the foreign key.

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; } = new HashSet<Location>();
}

public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the following line:

```
.WithMany()
```

Basically you are telling EF something like "I have a relationship between `Company` and `Location`, with FK column named `LocationId` (but no explicit `LocationId` property), `Company` reference navigation property in `Location` entity and **no collection navigation property** in `Company` entity".

So far so good. But when EF encounters `Locations` collection navigation property in `Company` entity, by convention it considers *another* relationship with no reference navigation property in `Location`, no FK property and auto generated FK column name. Which is definitely not what was your intention.

As a rule of thumb, make sure the fluent configuration always reflect the presence/absence of the navigation and FK properties. In your case, simply change the above line to

```
.WithMany(e => e.Locations)
```

and the issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the company model into this:

```
public class Company
{
     [Key]  // This tells the engine that the following property id the primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // this tells the engine that the following property's value is assigned by DB
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Now, why do you see the `Company_Id1` in the query? Because in entity framework, that's the default naming convention for the primary key. You are using a different name for the PK, so you need to define your primary key in the model using the `[Key]` data annotation.

Your inserts and updates should not assign the value of this column (DB should assign the value), that's why you need to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to your model.

Also, virtual is used for navigation properties (example: foreign keys), that's why I removed the `virtual` tag from the first two properties in the company model.

You need to do the same for the Locations model too.